# How to design inclusive icons/images representing different gender identity/preferences?

Tags: icons, accessibility, gender, inclusive-design, preferences

These days there is some consensus around how to address people with different gender preferences apart from male, female and other. The term GLBT has been used to provide some differentiation to include gay, lesbian, bisexual and transgender identity or preference. I was wondering whether the concept of male and female (and therefore the iconography associated with them) is deeply entrenched that it will be difficult to come up with an extension to cover these additional categories.

Are there examples of appropriate icons or images used to represent the spectrum of gender identity/preferences?

This is from Font Awesome:
[image]

Comment: there's also [this kind'a idea](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sexual-orientation-vector-icons-gender-human-445580170)...

Answer (score 5):

Through icons, we can specify or show anything we want. These types of icons are already in use in several websites. You can create your own (i recommend personally).

For an example here is FontAwesome's Gender Icon (For Design Inspiration)

https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_gender.asp

From the above you can get an idea, how to design one for yourself.

Comment: +1 for the reference. I have updated my question with it.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_symbol), you have the following icons to represent gender identity/preferences:

[image]